# How to link max(DATEDIFF) with subquery in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query to get Profile ID, Full Name and Contact Number of the tenant who has stayed with us for the longest time period in the past

where profile id is primary key in profiles and foreign key in tenant history. How do i execute date difference in table b and get info of table a

```
select profile_id, first_name+ ' '+ last_name as Full_Name , phone from dbo.Profiles where 
        profile_id=
        (SELECT profile_id from dbo.Tenancy_histories where  max(DATEDIFF(day,move_in_date,move_out_date));
```

Comment: Are you looking for max move_in_date where move_out_date is null.  Implying that they have not moved out and have the maximum move in historical date?  Or the person who has stayed there the longest regardless of if they are still there?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select profile_id, first_name+ ' '+ last_name as Full_Name , phone from dbo.Profiles where 
    profile_id=
    (SELECT top 1 profile_id from dbo.Tenancy_histories order by DATEDIFF(day,move_in_date,move_out_date);
```

Comment: `order by max(..)` ain't gonna work. If you have `top 1` then it's just `order by datediff(..) DESC`

Comment: Nice, go ahead and mark the answer! Thanks and thanks Nenad!